# JetBrains Teamcity Injector crashes when a test hangs in Swing

Tags: java, swing, testing, teamcity

I have a few Windows based machines for testing UI written in Java Swing. From time to time, these get stuck, time out and get killed. However TeamCity agent has a stacktraceDump plugin which often crashes when (probably) trying to get the thread dump.

This unfortunately shows a dialog in Windows saying that **JetBrains.TeamCity.Injector.exe stopped working**. This dialog then blocks the view and is a cause of consequent test failures (unable to click on an element etc).

Is there any way how to prevent this? Disabling the plugin completely would do as well.

Here are some more details about the crash. The system is Windows 7.

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: JetBrains.TeamCity.Injector.exe
  Application Version:  0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    55ca7faa
  Fault Module Name:    MSVCR100.dll
  Fault Module Version: 10.0.40219.1
  Fault Module Timestamp:   4d5f034a
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 000000000003c010
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    3081
  Additional Information 1: a88f
  Additional Information 2: a88fd65e279f2f2430f8931a3c56d353
  Additional Information 3: fe33
  Additional Information 4: fe33e26a5413ff31186b617fd3f50037
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found any solution to this, but here's a workaround. Add a command-line step in TeamCity with the following inline script:

```
:; exit 0
tskill WerFault
exit /b 0
```

This works on both Linux and Windows agents (the first line is ignored on Windows). It kills the application that shows the dialog with the error.